# matplotlib venn install on windows

Tags: matplotlib-venn

I've been trying to import matplotlib-venn into my ipynb, and I cannot do it. 
I installed the package and get the following:

I did pip install and easy install, and each time I go to load it onto my ipynb I get the following:

```
    ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-12-64848b9d607a> in <module>()
          7 import seaborn as sns
          8 import os
    ----> 9 from matplotlib_venn import venn3
         10 
         11 #Imports CSV

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib_venn'

    C:\WINDOWS\system32>easy_install matplotlib-venn
    Searching for matplotlib-venn
    Best match: matplotlib-venn 0.11.5
    Processing matplotlib_venn-0.11.5-py3.6.egg
    matplotlib-venn 0.11.5 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

    Using c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_venn-0.11.5-py3.6.egg
    Processing dependencies for matplotlib-venn
    Finished processing dependencies for matplotlib-venn

    C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install matplotlib-venn
    Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib-venn in c:\programdata        \anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_venn-0.11.5-py3.6.egg (0.11.5)
    Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib-venn) (2.2.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib-venn) (1.14.3)
    Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib-venn) (1.1.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->matplotlib-venn) (0.10.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->matplotlib-venn) (2.2.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->matplotlib-venn) (2.7.3)
    Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->matplotlib-venn) (2018.4)
    Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->matplotlib-venn) (1.11.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->matplotlib-venn) (1.0.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib->matplotlib-venn) (40.4.3)
```

I'm on a windows 10 machine, and it's not loading nor can I find any way to get it to load.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution, but a step-around. You're trying to install matplotlib-venn into what looks like your windows directory structure, rather than through your python kernel.

I've had success installing it directly into a jupyter notebook running on an ephemeral, linux-based cluster. That common environment might work better than a general install since a jupyter notebook uses an ipython kernel which should behave the same regardless of underlying os, but it's not exactly the answer.

From within Jupyter:

```
!easy_install matplotlib-venn
!conda config --add channels conda-forge
!conda config --set channel_priority strict
!conda install matplotlib-venn

import matplotlib_venn as mpv
```